# How to resolve ambiguous Kotlin method reference

Tags: kotlin

I define an enum that takes a method reference:

```
enum class Op(val param: (Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate) {
    GREATER_THAN(CriteriaBuilder::greaterThan)
}
```

There are two candidates in the `CriteriaBuilder` class, and the compiler can't figure out which one I mean ("Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match."):

```
<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> Predicate greaterThan(Expression<? extends Y> x, Expression<? extends Y> y);
<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> Predicate greaterThan(Expression<? extends Y> x, Y y);
```

Why can't Kotlin infer the right type? Clearly the first method is not possible. I can't figure out how to guide the compiler, casting it to the right type doesn't seem to work:

```
GREATER_THAN(CriteriaBuilder::greaterThan as (Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate)
```

Compiler complains "Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference".

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Java's `BiFunction` interface instead of a Kotlin function type `(Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate`?

Comment: Old habits, fixed!

Comment: Who is supposed to provide the `CriteriaBuilder` instance in your design? The definition of the enum itself, or the caller of `Op.param`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the [Javadoc of `CriteriaBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#greaterThan-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-Y-), the method you're referring to is not static.

Since you're not providing an instance of `CriteriaBuilder` in your function reference, this means that `CriteriaBuilder::greaterThan` actually expects a receiver or parameter of type `CriteriaBuilder` in addition to the 2 arguments, which doesn't match the signature that you're expecting: `(Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate`.

If you want the caller of `Op.param` to provide the criteria builder instance, then I suggest to change `Op.param`'s type to `(CriteriaBuilder, Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate` or `CriteriaBuilder.(Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate` - which would match the function reference `CriteriaBuilder::greaterThan`. The choice of which one to use depends on how you want to call it:

```kotlin
enum class Op(val param: CriteriaBuilder.(Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate) {
    GREATER_THAN(CriteriaBuilder::greaterThan)
}
// or

enum class Op(val param: (CriteriaBuilder, Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate) {
    GREATER_THAN(CriteriaBuilder::greaterThan)
}
```

If you want to have the `CriteriaBuilder` "built-in" the enum, you can instantiate it up front, and then use your specific instance in the function reference:

```kotlin
val yourCriteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder = TODO("create it somehow")

enum class Op(val param: (Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate) {
    GREATER_THAN(yourCriteriaBuilder::greaterThan)
}
```

I'm not familiar with the `CriteriaBuilder` API, so I'm not sure if this last option is actually desirable. You might want new instances each time instead - your call.

Comment: Thanks Joffrey for your detailed and thoughtful reply! I didn't know about the "CriteriaBuilder.(Expression<String>, String) -> Predicate" syntax, this is exactly what I need.